# Which ocean is going to be swallowed by the Supercontinent Cycle, Atlantic or Pacific?

Tags: geology, geophysics, plate-tectonics, models, earth-history

The register shows several supercontinents have been formed on Earth's History:

> "The most recent supercontinent, Pangaea, formed about 300 million
>   years ago (0.3 Ga). There are two different views on the history of
>   earlier supercontinents. The first proposes a series of
>   supercontinents: Vaalbara (c. 3.6 to c. 2.8 billion years ago); Ur (c.
>   3 billion years ago); Kenorland (c. 2.7 to 2.1 billion years ago);
>   Columbia (c. 1.8 to 1.5 billion years ago); Rodinia (c. 1.25 billion
>   to 750 million years ago); and Pannotia (c. 600 million years ago),
>   whose dispersal produced the fragments that ultimately collided to
>   form Pangaea".
>
> Source: [Supercontinent Cycle, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercontinent_cycle)

I would expect then a new supercontinent to form in some million years, but this implies Atlantic or Pacific Ocean, both with ocean-ridges and divergent margins, to disappear.

Wich one will be closed and wich one will survive to Supercontinent Cycle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pacific has already lost part its spreading center, north america has been pushed over it.. A few tiny non-contiguous plates like the  Juan de fuca plate is all that is left of the east pacific plate. in places like the san-andreas the north american plates has complete overridden the spreading center.

In truth there are four possible predictions for the future: [Novopangea, Pangea Ultima, Aurica and Amasia](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0921818118302054). two predict the atlantic disappearing one predicts the arctic and the final predicts the loss of the pacific. I think the latter two are more likely given what we see in the north america/pacific interaction but this is just opinion, the truth is we don't know a lot about how oceanic plates disappear or how spreading centers die because by their very nature they do not leave much evidence behind.

[image]

Comment: At my degree they said pacific dorsal was more powerfull than atlantic one, arguing it with tomography images of mantle where pacific area looked a more powerfull heat source

Comment: he truth is we are not entirely sure what controls the strength of a plates movement, more importantly we don't know how it changes they will interact in the long run. So saying one is  powerful really doesn't mean much.